# How to pass data in react js inside a file

Tags: reactjs

I have the next component in ReactJs:

```js
function App() {
function handleClick(e) {
    console.log('click ', e);
    localStorage.setItem('my-item', e.key);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('my-item'))
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu
        selectedKeys={e.key}   
        style={{ width: 500px}}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
      ...another code

}
```

There i used AntDesign. The function `handleClick` write in my localstorage the `key` of an item. It works, but i want to pass in `selectedKeys` the key that i passed in the localstorage, so i want to do this `selectedKeys={e.key}`, but i can't do this. How to pass the data `e.key` from the function to`<Menu>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

What about using a state :

With the React hook `useState` :

```
import React, { useState } from React;
```

then

```
const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = useState([]);
```

then

```
function handleClick(key) {
  localStorage.setItem('my-item', key);
  let newKeys = selectedKeys.slice(0); // you may need to clone the array
  newKeys.push(key);
  setSelectedKeys(newKeys); // or push it into an array if there is many.
}
```

your `Menu` component would then look like :

```
<Menu
 mode="inline"
 selectedKeys={selectedKeys}   
 openKeys={openKeys}
 onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
 style={{ width: 500px}}
 onClick={() => handleClick(e.key)}>
```

All together :

```
import React, { useState } from React;

const App = () => {
  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (key) => {
    localStorage.setItem('my-item', key);
    let newKeys = selectedKeys.slice(0); // you may need to clone the array
    newKeys.push(key);
    setSelectedKeys(newKeys); // or push it into an array if there is many.
  }

  return {
    <Menu
     mode="inline"
     selectedKeys={selectedKeys}   
     openKeys={openKeys}
     onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
     style={{ width: 500px}}
     onClick={() => handleClick(e.key)}>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a class component and in the state make an attribute of selected key and in the handleClick do set the state and assign the selectedKey value from the state in the Menu tag. Thats the proper way of doing it.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedKey: null
    };
  }
  handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log('click ', e);
    this.setState({
       selectedKey: e.key         
    });
    localStorage.setItem('my-item', e.key);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('my-item'));
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu
          selectedKeys={this.state.selectedKey}   
          style={{ width: 500px}}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
        ...another code
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mteuahasan did it in haste. appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Use an arrow function:

```
onClick={() => handleClick(e.key)}
```

In your code:

```
  handleClick = key => {
    console.log("the key is:", key);
    localStorage.setItem('my-item', key);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('my-item'))
  }

  <Menu
    selectedKeys={e.key}   
    style={{ width: 500px}}
    onClick={() => handleClick(e.key)}>
```